# How to access raw ForeignKey value directly in Django ORM and use it in search_fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

Let's say I have these models:

```
class First(models.Model):
    id = models.SlugField(primary_key=True)

class Second(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey('First')
```

This technically means that `Second.foo` is a `SlugField` that points to the primary key of `First` model.

The question is how can I access that raw value in `foo` without referencing and working with `First` model?

**Bonus question:** How to make this field searchable in Django Admin panel without pointing to a sub model field?

So how to do something like this?

```
@admin.register(Second)
class SecondAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['foo_id',]
```

Instead of this?

```
@admin.register(Second)
class SecondAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['foo__id',]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the main question is to add **`_id`** at the end of the variable that is being referenced:

```
Second.objects.filter(foo_id='something')
```